# Grails Async Response Rendering vs Servlet 3.0 Asynchronous Rendering

Tags: servlets, grails, asynchronous, promise

I have a method in the controller that is supposed to return JSON.

As per my interpretation of the [grails async docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.2/guide/async.html) , under the sub topic Async Response Rendering, I could wrap my I/O call with the task construct
`task{}` and that should do the async response rendering.

So my method looks like

```
def getSomeJSON() { 
    task {
        def someList = someService.getList()
        render([key: someList] as JSON)
    }
}
```

The method works fine but I see my logs have many errors that say

```
ERROR o.g.a.f.gpars.LoggingPoolFactory - Async execution error: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

I'm not sure what is causing this. I'm unable to reproduce this on my local machine.

So my question is what is wrong with the above snippet of code ?
Is my interpretation of the doc wrong ?

How is this different from **"Servlet 3.0 Asynchronous Rendering"**

EDIT:

I updated my method as follows:

```
import static grails.async.Promises.*

    def getSomeJSON() { 
            Promise jsonPromise = task {
                def someList = someService.getList()
                render([key: someList] as JSON)
            }
            jsonPromise
        }
```

So the change I am doing here is explicitly returning the Promise from the controller method as advised in the docs. To quote the docs:

> This is done by returning a Promise instance from the controller
>   action.

But I still get the error:

```
ERROR o.g.a.f.gpars.LoggingPoolFactory - Async execution error: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.notifyAttributeAssigned(Request.java:1547) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1538) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar:7.0.54]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.storeGrailsWebRequest(WebUtils.java:431) ~[grails-web-common-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.async.WebRequestPromsiseDecorator$_decorate_closure1.doCall(WebRequestPromiseDecoratorLookupStrategy.groovy:55) ~[grails-plugin-async-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.async.WebRequestPromsiseDecorator$_decorate_closure1.call(WebRequestPromiseDecoratorLookupStrategy.groovy) ~[grails-plugin-async-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.grails.async.factory.gpars.GparsPromise$_onError_closure2.doCall(GparsPromise.groovy:72) ~[grails-async-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.grails.async.factory.gpars.GparsPromise$_onError_closure2.call(GparsPromise.groovy) ~[grails-async-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataCallback$1.run(DataCallback.java:62) ~[gpars-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
```

Comment: Is "someService" actually being injected in your class (I presume it's a Controller)?  That would seem to be the only obvious candidate for a NPE.

Comment: I did not paste the whole class here, it is injected to the class and the service returns the response right

Comment: Might be similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356538/asynchronous-programming-in-grails

Comment: i did see that question before I posted mine, they do not seem to be related